# how to adjust the size of app name in action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am working on an android project. The name I have given to my application is long enough to not fit in the default size of the action bar. Can anyone tell me how can I marquee text.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the text size of action bar title as below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />
```

and override the default title size in a custom style:

```
<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

hope this work!